# BigQuery dataset deletion and name reuse

Tags: google-bigquery

When I delete a dataset in BigQuery and create another one, in the same project but in a different region, with the same dataset name, this throws an error. It simply says 'Not found: Dataset 'projectId:datasetName' '

This is an important problem, as GA360 imports rely on having the dataset named with the view ID. Now that we have BigQuery in Australia, we would like to be able to use it.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

False alarm. It turns out that BQ just needs some more time to complete this operation. I tried again after some minutes and it now works.

Comment: No need to be sorry, it's useful for people to know